# Capitalization with Command Line Inputs [C++ 98][g++]

Tags: c++, command-line, command-line-arguments, capitalization

I'm having an issue with command line inputs. Here's a simple program that will only print out the last command line argument.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << argv[argc-1] << std::endl;
}
```

But here are some outputs from the program with the following command line inputs.

```
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/os"
/OS
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/Os"
/OS
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/oS"
/OS
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/OS"
/OS
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/hp"
/hp
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/hP"
/hp
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/Hp"
/hp
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop>test.exe "/HP"
/hp
```

This seems like a small issue, but this has bad results on a project that I'm working on. Is this a weird problem? Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Also, this program works perfectly with every other input. It's only those listed that have a problem.

Comment: Is this happening on every machine? It seems like a weird thing that could only be caused by a specific shells environment

Comment: It's only happening on my machine.

Comment: So try with a fresh command line. Try with a command line as a different user. AKA do some troubleshooting. Check your environment for suspicious settings